# How to change font size in existing visual studio class diagram?

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I want to make text smaller, not zoom diagram but change font size.
Is it possible?

Comment: do you mean to increase size for all pages in visual studio ?

Comment: no, only for current diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution:

Open *.cd file with text editor.
Find string in the end of file like this:

```
<Font Name="Consolas" Size="7" />
```

Change it.

Comment: Hi Eugine, I am experiencing similar issue. I've generated the class diagram via VS2012 Ultimate, (.classdiagram extension), but after I applied your advice,I was not able to find the font node. Do you have any advice regarding this?

Comment: I did it in Professional version only.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by setting font size and more in the options menu of VS:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/566e3e74-5955-431f-bc58-f92f68effa39/changing-font-size-in-class-diagram-vs2012

Reopen your diagram and everything will be adjusted.